# Terraform error 'oraclecloud: can not create client, bad configuration: failed to read base64 '

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to generate acme certificate for the records under hosted zone. But its throwing error

acme_certificate.example_cert: Creating...
╷
│ Error: error configuring plugin: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error initializing provider: oraclecloud: can not create client, bad configuration: failed to read base64 value /Users/imtiaz/.oci/oci_api_key.pem (defined by env var OCI_PRIVKEY): illegal base64 data at input byte 16

```
resource "acme_certificate" "example_cert" {
account_key_pem = file("${var.acme_account_key}")
common_name     = "test.example.io"
dns_challenge {
  provider = "oraclecloud"
  config = {
    OCI_COMPARTMENT_OCID = var.compartment_ocid
    OCI_TENANCY_OCID = var.tenancy_ocid
    OCI_USER_OCID = var.user_ocid
    OCI_REGION = var.region
    OCI_PUBKEY_FINGERPRINT = var.fingerprint
    OCI_PRIVKEY = var.private_key_path
  }
```

I am able to create hosted zones, records unders hosted zone and bucket in oracle cloud using same private key. Now I am trying to generate acme certificate for dns records but its throwing above exception.

Comment: Isn't the provider called `oci`?

Comment: I had tried that but for DNS challenge, we have to use Oraclecloud getting below error if you use oci provider Error: error configuring plugin: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = unknown provider name "oci" . The oraclecloud is similar to route53 in aws

Comment: Ah, ok, but I think the variable name is not `OCI_PRIVKEY` but rather `OCI_PRIVKEY_FILE`. More info here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/getstackhead/acme/latest/docs/guides/dns-providers-oraclecloud#argument-reference.

Comment: @MarkoE Thanks for the response. The  error failed to read base64 value is gone. Now I am getting "oraclecloud: Service error:NotAuthorizedOrNotFound. Authorization failed or requested resource not found.. http status code: 404."